# Two monotone simplexes in the product space are "disjoint"

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, algebraic-topology

Let $x_0,x_1,\dots,x_p$ be $p+1$ points in general position in $\mathbb R^p$, and let $y_0,y_1,\dots,y_q$ be $q+1$ points in general position in $\mathbb R^q$. Now consider the $(p+1)(q+1)$ points (denote the set $P$) in the product space $\mathbb R^{p+q}$. Let $\sigma=\{(a_0,b_0),(a_1,b_1),\dots,(a_{p+q},b_{p+q})\}$ ($a_k=x_i$, $b_k=y_j$) be a subset of $P$ with $(p+q+1)$ elements. If for every $(a_k,b_k)=(x_i,y_j)$ one has $(a_{k+1},b_{k+1})=(x_{i+1},y_j)$ or $=(x_i,y_{j+1})$, we call this $\sigma$ *monotone*. It is easy to check that the $(p+q+1)$ points in a monotone subset are in general position, hence they span a $(p+q)$-simplex in $\mathbb R^{p+q}$. Therefore we call this $\sigma$ a *monotone simplex* and identify this subset with the simplex in $\mathbb R^{p+q}$.

Now let $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ be two different monotone simplexes. I want to show that their interiors are disjoint. I have convinced myself this is true by the intuition from some low dimensional cases, but I do not how to prove it in general.

Any hint or reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to show this in the special case where
$$x_i = (\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{i}, \underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{p-i}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_j = (\underbrace{1,1,\dots,1}_{j}, \underbrace{0,0,\dots,0}_{q-j}).$$
In this case, for any monotone simplex $\sigma$, $\sigma_k$ is a point with $k$ coordinates that are $1$ and $p+q-k$ coordinates that are $0$. From $k$ to $k+1$, exactly one coordinate changes from $0$ to $1$. In other words, each monotone simplex $\sigma$ is a coordinate permutation of the simplex which has
\begin{align}
\sigma_0 &= (0,0,\dots,0) \\
\sigma_1 &= (1,0,\dots,0) \\
\vdots\  &= \ \vdots \\
\sigma_{p+q} &= (1,1,\dots,1).
\end{align}
The interior of this simplex consists of all points $(u_0,u_1, \dots, u_{p+q})$ with $$1 > u_0 > u_1 > \dots > u_{p+q} > 0.$$
After a permutation $\pi$ of the coordinates, we get a simplex $\sigma_\pi$ whose convex hull consists of all points $(u_0, u_1, \dots, u_{p+q})$ with $$1 > u_{\pi(0)} > u_{\pi(1)} > \dots > u_{\pi(p+q)} > 0.$$ All monotone simplices can be written in this way, though we also get some non-monotone simplices. (We get a monotone simplex if the relative ordering of the coordinates coming from $x$, and the relative ordering of the coordinates coming from $y$, are maintained. But this doesn't really matter.)

Given two different monotone simplices $\sigma_\pi$ and $\sigma_{\pi'}$, there will be some $i$ and $j$ such that $\pi^{-1}(i) < \pi^{-1}(j)$ but $\pi'^{-1}(i) > \pi'^{-1}(j)$. In that case, all points in the interior of $\sigma_\pi$ satisfy  $u_i < u_j$, but all points in the interior of $\sigma_{\pi'}$ satisfy $u_i > u_j$, so they are disjoint.

---

To reduce to this special case, note that any simplex in $\mathbb R^p$ is an affine transformation of the $x$ simplex above, and any simplex in $\mathbb R^q$ is an affine transformation of the $y$ simplex above. The product of these two transformations is an affine transformation of $\mathbb R^{p+q}$.

So for arbitrary $x$, $y$ in general position, we can turn their monotone simplices into the monotone simplices above by an affine transformation. But affine transformations are bijective and preserve linear inequalities. The interiors of the images of two monotone simplices will be disjoint, so the interiors of any two monotone simplices will themselves be disjoint.